# Timezone shows UTC in Outlook when created by graph api

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

When creating an calendar event via MS Graph API the event looks different in the OWA and the Outlook Client.

In the Outlook client the event shows up ok in the overview, but when looking at the details it is shown in UTC instead of my timezone (Western Europe) and I cannot click/unclick the timezone button. If I open the same event in OWA it shows up in the correct timezone. Also if I send the event to another organisation it also shows up ok.

This leads me to believe it's something in our outlook client, but then I cannot see any difference in the graph API between events created from Outlook directly (looks ok) and the ones created via a rest call.

This is my payload

```
{
"subject": "tEST",
"organizer": {
    "emailaddress": {
        "address": "<email>"
    }
},
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-10-09T08:01:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
},
"end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-10-09T09:01:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
},
"attendees": [
    {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Mattias Johansson",
            "address": "<email>"
        },
        "type": "optional"
    }
],
"reminderminutesbeforestart": 15
```

}

and this is a screenshot of the booking, the time is slightly different since it's another booking than the payload.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Z` suffix to the time? `2019-10-09T08:01:00Z`

Comment: Yes, with the same result

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an Outlook client issue. Determining the time zone is handled on the client and it sounds like it is either misconfigured or failing to do the transposing.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna resurrect this question, has I have stumbled upon it many time while searching for a solution to this problem.

I for a while thought it was a bug or a config problem in Outlook's client but it turns out it was how I formatted the datetime in my Azure event request. Thanks to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217247/microsoft-graph-api-create-event-always-create-meeting-with-utc-timezone) I tried to manually format my time to remove all other artefacts of UTC dates, like `Z` or `+02:00`.

My guess is the timezone you pass with the datetime is overriden by Azure if there is anything looking like a UTC date in datetime.

"Good" datetime looks like `2023-07-12T08:00:00`

"Bad" datetime would be `2023-07-12T06:00:00+02:00` or `2023-07-12T06:00:00Z`

Answer (score 0):

We solved the issue. The issue was that the Graph API accepts "invalid timezones" without an error and just does something. The Timezone has to stick exactly to their definition. I think these should be those timezones here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone